# fgets doesn't read in at most one less than size characters from stream

Tags: c, while-loop, char, newline, fgets

I am learning fgets from the manpage. I did some tests on fgets to make sure I understand it. One of the tests I did results in behaviour contrary to what is specified in the man page. The man page says:

> ```
> char *fgets(char s[restrict .size], int size, FILE *restrict stream);
> ```
>
> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
> stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF
> or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A
> terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the
> buffer.

But it doesn't "read in at most one less than size characters from stream". As demonstrated by the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("sample", "r");
    char *s=calloc(50, sizeof(char));
    while(fgets(s,2,fp)!=NULL)  printf("%s",s);
}
```

The sample file:

```
thiis is line no. 1
joke joke 2 joke joke
arch linux btw 3
4th line
5th line
```

The output of the compiled binary:

```
thiis is line no. 1
joke joke 2 joke joke
arch linux btw 3
4th line
5th line
```

The expected output according to the man page:

```
t
j
a
4
5
```

Is the man page wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: The output is correct. It reads at most 1 char or a new line \n. It doesn't drop other chars, it reads them on next calls in the loop.

Comment: Change `printf("%s",s);` to `printf("%s--",s);` and you'll see `fgets()` is doing what it claims to do.

Comment: You request to read 1 char in the loop. It reads one char, next char, next char. It doesn't drop chars if a buffer is smaller than a line.

Comment: how do i mark it solved?

Comment: @heman: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Or you can simply delete it if you think the question would not be useful to other readers. Since your question is based on a misunderstanding on your part, it may be better to simply delete it. If your question does not get upvoted, it will probably [be automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) anyway, after a certain time period.

Comment: Or just do `printf("|%s|",s);`

Comment: To output the 1st char only `while (fgets(s,50,fp)) { printf ("%c\n", *s); }` (this will output the 1st character from each read of up to `49` chars with `fgets()` followed by a newline) You can replace the `printf()` with `putchar(*s); putchar('\n');`

Comment: There isn't much point in using `calloc()` to allocate 50 bytes — you could use `char s[50];` instead.  Or, indeed, you could use `char s[2];` since you tell `fgets()` the array size is 2 bytes.  If you do use `calloc()`, you should probably also use `free(s)` before the end of the function, and you should definitely check that `calloc()` was successful before trying to use the allocated space.  Granted, in this program it isn't a big problem — the memory allocation is not likely to fail and the leaked memory is cleaned up as the program exits.  But it's best to use good habits from the start.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nice info. Doesnt it automatically free the memory at the end of the main function though?

Comment: Yes; the dynamically allocated memory is all released when the program terminates.  That's why I said “in this program, it isn't a big problem”.  However, in other contexts, not freeing the memory means that the memory is leaked, and the program may run out of memory because too much has been leaked.  And it's likely that the program will terminate abruptly.  So, it's a good habit to make sure you know where any allocated resource will be released — memory, file streams, any resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the man page wrong or am i missing something?

I won't say that the man page is wrong but it could be more clear.

There are 3 things that may stop `fgets` from reading from the stream.

1. The buffer is full (i.e. only room left for the termination character)
2. A newline character was read from the stream
3. End-Of-File occured

The quoted man page only mentions two of those conditions clearly.

> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.

That is #2 and #3 are mentioned very explicit while #1 is (kind of) derived from

> reads in at most one less than size characters from stream

Here is another description from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html

> ... read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s until n-1 bytes are read, **or** a newline is read and transferred to s, **or** an end-of-file condition is encountered.

where the 3 cases are clearly mentioned.

But yes... you are missing something. Once the buffer gets full, the rest of the current line is **not read and discarded**. The rest will stay in the stream and be available for the next read. So nothing is lost. You just need more `fgets` calls to read all data.

As suggested in a number of comments (e.g. Fe2O3 and Lundin) you can see this if you change the print statement so that it includes a delimiter of some kind. For instance (from Lundin):

```
printf("|%s|",s);
```

This will make clear exactly what you got from the individual `fgets` calls.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided quote there is writte clear

> If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

Where do you see that this call `fgets(s,2,fp)` reads the new line character for example when reading this line?

```
thiis is line no. 1
```

The line contains only one new line character at its end.

This call reads only one character after another that is character by character that is appended by the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

So the read strings look like

```
{ 't', '\0' }
{ 'h', '\0' },
{ 'i', '\0' }
// ...
{ '1', '\0' }
{ '\n', '\0' }
```

If you have a call of  `fgets` like that

```
fgets(s,n,fp)
```

then at most `n-1` characters are read from the input stream. One character is reserved for the terminating zero character `'\0'` to build a string.

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 2 **The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
> characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
> the array pointed to by s**. No additional characters are read after a
> new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. **A null
> character is written immediately after the last character read into
> the array**